# How to add an header to a GridView?

Tags: java, android, layout, gridview

I have a `GridView` which is a calendar. I want to add the day names in a row above.

I tried creating a layout above the `GridView` but it does not fit in every device.

I also don't want to add the header as cells in the grid, because I want them to look different than other cells.

Is it possible to add a header to the `GridView` that will be aligned according to the columns?

This is a picture of my `GridView`:

[image]

Is there any way to add an header line? or at least get the size of each column on the screen and do a calculation to determine what margins are required between each `TextView` in the `Layout` above the `GridView`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you have to add 7 to getCount() method of your adapter because you need an additional 7 cells as a header

Then, in your getView() method of your adapter your have to check if positions are 0 to 6 then create your header cells such as Mon Tue and etc.